# deprecation warning on ember data models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, deprecated

Just updated to ember v1.12.0-beta.1 and ember-data v1.0.0-beta.16. I'm getting the following deprecation warning on the fields in my models:

```
DEPRECATION: Using the same function as getter and setter is deprecated. See http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_deprecate-using-the-same-function-as-getter-and-setter-in-computed-properties for more details.
```

The Ember inspector Deprecations view is pointing to all my models. So I basically get one deprecation error per line in my model. Here is an example model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    userid: DS.attr('number'),
    unitid: DS.attr('number'),
    log: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    start_date: DS.attr('date'),
    end_date: DS.attr('date'),
    duration_mins: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Comment: You should consider opening an issue on GitHub for Ember or Ember-Data.  Not sure Stack is the right place for this.

Comment: @rog I expected something to be in there by now if this is legit.

Comment: A fix for this allready made it's way into master: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2959

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @albertjan said this is a bug and there's already a [fix](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2959). Upgrading to the latest version of [Ember Data beta 17](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-fix-the-deprecation-using-the-same-function-as-getter-and-setter-is-deprecated/7987) or greater will resolve it.

Making this a community wiki answer so no-one misses the comment.